# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'module_desc'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have another post where I implemented changes advised by a user so fix my issue with being able to update my listview but I still get the following error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'module_desc', table 'E:\SVN
>   WEBSITE COPIES\CIT\CIT5\APP_DATA\UNIDB.MDF.dbo.modules'; column does
>   not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.

Below is my current code...

```
asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [module_id], [module_name], [module_desc], [module_units] 
    FROM [modules]"

    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [modules] SET [module_name]= @Module_Name, [module_desc]=@Module_Description, 
    [module_units]=@Module_Units WHERE [module_id] = @Module_ID" >

<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Description" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Units" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Module_ID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>


</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="Module_ID">
```

Everything seems to be perfect code wise so I'm not sure how to get past this issue.

Any help would be great...

RD

Answer (score 0):

You error message is self explanatory, the column `module_desc` does not allow null values. Either you will have to allow nulls in the column or else pass a default value. What I suspect is happening with your code is user is entering an empty text and by default `SqlDataSource` control converts that to `Null`.  You will have to set the property `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to false like this:-

```
<UpdateParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Name" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Description" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
  <asp:Parameter Name="Module_Units" Type="Int32" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="Module_ID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

This will not convert the empty text to `Null` and will update empty text itself in database instead of `Null`.

Comment: Rahul, it still brings up the same error with that piece of code added in, theres values being added in, for example when I edit the first module and say I write test into the fields and tried to update it barks that error out...

Comment: @ryanfc2 - Are you sure you are not passing an empty string? Try running a sql server profiler and see what query it is passing.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm just using the sql connection to connect to db, then using list view to view the table within the db i want to see, the list view works in that it displays the data I want but when I go to edit it and submit the changes it gives that error, not sure why its doing the null because when I update the description I am adding more data to whats already there

Comment: @ryanfc2 - Yeah please refer to some very basic video on how to use SQL server profiler it's really easy. You will be able to identify the issue cz without that no one can help.

Comment: I cant seem to find this feature on my VS 2015 copy, When I add nulls allowed into module desc box it works in that it lets me update but it makes the module desc information dissappear and it dosent view.

Comment: @ryanfc2- Actually sql server profiler opens up from SSMS.